# ActiveMQ throwing Unmatched acknowledge exception

Tags: java, spring, queue, jms, activemq-classic

```
WARN | Async error occurred: javax.jms.JMSException: Unmatched acknowledge: MessageAck {commandId = 30, responseRequired = false, ackType = 2, consumerId = ID:PC02-DT-009-52405-1421153309991-1:3:10:1, firstMessageId = ID:PC02-DT-009-52360-1421152976467-1:4:11:1:1, lastMessageId = ID:PC02-DT-009-52360-1421152976467-1:4:11:1:1, destination = queue://DATA.DESTINATION, transactionId = null, messageCount = 1, poisonCause = null}; Could not find Message-ID ID:PC02-DT-009-52360-1421152976467-1:4:11:1:1 in dispatched-list (start of ack)
javax.jms.JMSException: Unmatched acknowledge: MessageAck {commandId = 30, responseRequired = false, ackType = 2, consumerId = ID:PC02-DT-009-52405-1421153309991-1:3:10:1, firstMessageId = ID:PC02-DT-009-52360-1421152976467-1:4:11:1:1, lastMessageId = ID:PC02-DT-009-52360-1421152976467-1:4:11:1:1, destination = queue://DATA.DESTINATION, transactionId = null, messageCount = 1, poisonCause = null}; Could not find Message-ID ID:PC02-DT-009-52360-1421152976467-1:4:11:1:1 in dispatched-list (start of ack)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription.assertAckMatchesDispatched(PrefetchSubscription.java:482)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.PrefetchSubscription.acknowledge(PrefetchSubscription.java:214)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.AbstractRegion.acknowledge(AbstractRegion.java:426)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.region.RegionBroker.acknowledge(RegionBroker.java:408)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.acknowledge(BrokerFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFilter.acknowledge(BrokerFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransactionBroker.acknowledge(TransactionBroker.java:287)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.acknowledge(MutableBrokerFilter.java:87)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processMessageAck(TransportConnection.java:508)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.MessageAck.visit(MessageAck.java:236)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:329)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:184)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.onCommand(MutexTransport.java:50)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onCommand(WireFormatNegotiator.java:113)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:288)
    atorg.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:214)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
```

That's the exception I get in the activeMQ log.
Scenario: I have 10 consumers, and I have 100 messages in the destination queue to which the consumers are listening. Consumers are fetching the messages for some 10-20 messages but eventually stops fetching the messages from queue with the above exception. My understanding is that a consumer will be given a new message only on returning an acknowledgement(if I'm right that is)..
JMS container:

`<jms:listener-container container-type="default" connection-factory="jmsConsumerConnectionFactory"
                            acknowledge="auto">
        <jms:listener destination="DATA.DESTINATION" ref="jmsMessageListener" concurrency="10-15" method="onMessage"/>
    </jms:listener-container>`

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Well, let me thank myself for answering this. Apparently the consumers were running into some exceptions  when connecting to a DB via httpclient, which was killing all the consumer threads.
Anyways, anybody having this issue without any exceptions happening can try and resolve by,
1. Increasing the memory limit in activeMQ config "conf/activemq.xml"
2. Try changing the acknowledgement method to "transacted" or acknowledge in the message itself
message.acknowledge();

Comment: Can you explain how the two changes you recommend to anyone else who hits this problem would resolve the exceptions you were seeing?

Comment: Also, it sounds like maybe there was a problem with exception-handling in whatever JMS consumer library you were using (Spring's DMLC, maybe?).  If that might be the case, I'd encourage you to submit a bug report against that library, because exceptions shouldn't result in consumers being unable to allow the message to fail and be moved to a DLQ.  Unless you're saying that your application logic was preventing the exception from propagating out of your own code?